# Does there exist a vector α st the equality holds?

Tags: kernel-trick

A training set $(x_1,y_1),...,(x_m,y_m)$ is generic iff $x_i=x_j$ then $y_i=y_j$ and let's consider the following kernel $K_a(x,t)=\prod_{i=1}^n(1+(x_it_i)+(1-x_i)(1-t_i))$

Given a generic training set $(x_1,y_1),...,(x_m,y_m) \in \{0,1\}^nx\{0,1\}$ does there necessarily exist a vector $\alpha \in R^m$ such that
$$\sum_{j=1}^m(\sum_{i=1}^m (\alpha_iK_a(x_i,x_j)-y_j)^2=0$$

Any idea how this could be solved? Any tip would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag

Comment: You should distinguish between set index and what I assume is dimension index within the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

In matrix notation, your equation is $$\|AK-ey^T\|_F=0$$ where $A=\textrm{diag}(\alpha)$ and $K_{i,j}=K_a(x_i,x_j)$. This requires equality of matrices. $\textrm{rank}(A)=m$, $0\leq\textrm{rank}(K)=k\leq m$ which depends on the training set, and the outer product has rank 1. AK will therefore also have rank $k$, and the Frobenius norm can only be zero if $k=1$, and particularly $K=vy^T$ and $Av=e$. Therefore existence of such a vector depends on the training set.